# Не удаётся считать значение свойства объекта в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, properties

Нужно считать значение свойства генерируемого рандомом, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?
Когда проверяю значения свойств, то везде пишет indefined

```js
client[1]={
 intervalVhod:5,
 intervalSrv:11,
 input:5,
 startSrv:5,
 endSrv:16,
 wait:0

};

for (var i=2;i<11;i++){

 client[i]={
 intervalVhod:parseInt(Math.random()*(7-2)+2),
 intervalSrv:parseInt(Math.random()*(16-2)+2),
 input:client[i-1].startSrv+client[i-1].intervalSrv, 
 

};
console.log(client[i]);

for (key in client[i]) {
  console.log(key+" "+client[key]);
}

}
```

[image: Вот что получается в консоли]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пропущено `[i]` в

```
console.log(key + " " + client[i][key]);
```

```js
var client = [];

client[1] = {
  intervalVhod: 5,
  intervalSrv: 11,
  input: 5,
  startSrv: 5,
  endSrv: 16,
  wait: 0

};

for (var i = 2; i < 11; i++) {

  var intervalVhod = Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 2) + 2); 
  var intervalSrv = Math.floor(Math.random() * (16 - 2) + 2);
  var input = client[i - 1].startSrv + client[i - 1].intervalSrv;

  client[i] = {
    intervalVhod: intervalVhod,
    intervalSrv: intervalSrv,
    input: input,
    startSrv: 0
  };
  console.log(client[i]);

  for (key in client[i]) {
    console.log(key + " " + client[i][key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Действительно, спасибо большое. Стало выводить значение
Но значение я всё равно не могу считать в переменную какую-либо(

Comment: @MatthewYakovlev "Но значение я всё равно не могу считать в переменную какую-либо" - 
можете, только Вы делаете это неправильно.

Comment: Буду весьма признателен, если покажете код, просто я совсем новичок еще(

Comment: @MatthewYakovlev Какое значение и в какую переменную?

Comment: intervalVhod , intervalSrv,  input
Можно создать любые переменные локальные чтобы я мог в цикле с их помощью рассчитать значения для свойств следующего объекта, создаваемого в цикле

Comment: @MatthewYakovlev Добавьте код, который не работает, в вопрос - под вопросом ссылка "править".